# change color of the text cancel button in sweetalert

Tags: sweetalert2

how do i change the color of the text in cancel button in sweetalert2?

i have tried using custom class but it still doesn't work

```js
  return Swal.fire({
    text: label,
    customClass: {
      cancelButtonText: 'custom-cancelButtonText-class',
    },
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
    cancelButtonText: 'No',
    confirmButtonColor: '#FFF000',
    reverseButtons: true,
  })
```

my css

```css
.custom-cancelButtonText-class{
    color: #F04249
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`cancelButtonText: '<p style='color:#F04249'> No </p>',`

```
  return Swal.fire({
    text: label,
    customClass: {
      cancelButtonText: 'custom-cancelButtonText-class',
    },
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
    cancelButtonText: '<p style='color:#F04249'> No </p>',
    confirmButtonColor: '#FFF000',
    reverseButtons: true,
  })
```